# Type definitions across modules

Tags: module, types, ocaml

```
module type ELEMENT =
sig
    type element_i
end

module Element:ELEMENT =
struct  
    type element_i =  N of int | CNN of cnn
end

module type SEMIRING =
functor (E:ELEMENT)->
sig
    type elements
end

module Semiring:SEMIRING =
functor(Element:ELEMENT) ->
struct
        let zero = (Element.element_i  0) (*ERROR: Unbounded Value; Same with N 0*)
end
```

How can I create objects of the type element_i inside Semiring module here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can allow the programmer to create values of type `element_i` inside `Semiring` by not hiding the constructors of this type, as you are currently doing.

Instead, define the signature `ELEMENT` as:

```
module type ELEMENT =
sig
    type element_i = N of int | CNN of cnn
end
```

This makes your functor `Semiring` expect more of its `Element` argument: instead of any type `Element.element_i`, it now only accepts a type with exactly these constructors. But on the plus side it can now apply the constructors to build values of this type, for instance `Element.N 12`

Answer (score 2):

There's actually two problems with your example. The first is pointed out by Pascal (i.e., the constructors of `element_i` are hidden by the signature). The second is that the module `Element` in the functor is not the same as module `Element` you declared above. The `Element` argument to the functor is a "hiding" the definition of `Element` the same way a function parameter would "hide" a variable:

```
let x = 0

let f = fun x -> (* x here is a different x... *)

module type T = sig (* ... *) end

module M : T = struct (* ... *) end

module F = functor (M : T) -> (* M here is a different M... *)
```